# How would one disable Nagle's algorithm in Linux?

Tags: linux, nagle

Is there a way to do it through the command line? man tcp tells me that I need to set tcp_nodelay=1, but I am unable to create the tcp_nodelay file under /proc/sys/net/ipv4. Please let me know if there's any way of disabling Nagle in Linux.

Comment: Do you want this to be system-wide?

Comment: Yea, ideally i would like it system wide

Answer (score 42):

This flag (`TCP_NODELAY`) is an option that can be enabled on a per-socket basis and is applied when you create a TCP socket. This is done for a purpose: Nagle's algorithm is generally useful and helps handle network congestion. I doubt you want to disable it system-wide since your system will probably suffer from this deactivation.

To disable it for a given socket, you can apply the option `TCP_NODELAY` as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.16.shtml) in C:

```
int flag = 1;
int result = setsockopt(sock,            /* socket affected */
                        IPPROTO_TCP,     /* set option at TCP level */
                        TCP_NODELAY,     /* name of option */
                        (char *) &flag,  /* the cast is historical cruft */
                        sizeof(int));    /* length of option value */
 if (result < 0)
    ... handle the error ...
```

You may have to adapt to your programming language, but basically it sets the `TCP_NODELAY` flag option to the socket `sock`, effectively disabling Nagle's algorithm. This is valid on any OS with sockets supporting the TCP standard.

If you still want to disable Nagle's algorithm system-wide, two options are available. First, you could recompile your kernel using the according flag (see your distribution manual for this). The second option is to create a software that sets the `TCP_NODELAY` flag on every existing connection, similar to [this code](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/tcp_nodelay.txt). The latter option should be executed each time a new TCP connection is created on the system.

Something a bit cleaner would be to activate the low latency mode of TCP:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_low_latency
```

**update**: tcp_low_latency was removed in kernel v4.14 and above.

This will give a hint to the TCP stack as to which decisions to make in order to lower the latency (Which I guess is what you are trying to achieve by disabling Nagle's algorithm). By default, it is set to optimize bandwidth ( "0" will be read from `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_low_latency` ).

Comment: Your answer is correct but why do you cast `&flag` to `char *`? `setsockopt` expects a `const void *` value pointer, so casting to a type is not required (every type can implicitly cast to `void *`): http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsockopt.html Actually you even violate the C standard, as casting a pointer of type A to a pointer of type B where neither type is `void *` is actually undefined behavior by ISO-C. You have a pointer to an int but you claim it's a pointer to a `char *` (will work on almost all systems but is technically undefined)

Comment: This code is not mine, but a copy-paste the second link as I stated. You might want to contact www.unixguide.net about this issue. I remember seeing a couple of different signatures for `setsockopt()`, some of which (like the first link I provided) use a `char *` for the `flag` parameter. I don't mind changing the answer, as long as there are references to a credible `setsockopt()` prototype and an a code example to perform the desired operation.

Comment: agreed with Soravux : from  Microsoft MSDN:   int setsockopt( SOCKET s, int level, int optname, const char *optval, int optlen );   from linux man pages int setsockopt(int sockfd, int level, int optname, const void *optval, socklen_t optlen);  from vxWorks socklib STATUS setsockopt ( int s, int level, int optname, char * optval, int    optlen) and from IBM aix 7.1  int setsockopt (Socket, Level, OptionName, OptionValue, OptionLength) int  Socket,  Level,  OptionName; const void * OptionValue; socklen_t  OptionLength;

Comment: Note that as of kernel v4.14 the tcp_low_latency no longer does anything.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b6690b14386698ce2c19309abad3f17656bdfaea#diff-ebf8916b6537cea0d23e1e0cd6abab61R356